# How to setup web hooks to send message to Slack when Firebase functions crash?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I need to actively receive crash notifications for firebase functions.

Is there any way to set up Slack webhooks to receive a message when Firebase Functions throw an Error, functions crash, or something like that?

I would love to receive issue messages by velocity ie: Firebase Functions crash 50 times a day.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First you have to create a [log based (counter) metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics) that will be counting specific error occurencies and second - you create alerting policy with Slack notification channel.**

Let's start from [finding corresponding logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface) that appear when the function throws an error. Since I didn't have one that would crash I used logs that indicated that it was started.

[image]

Next you have to [create a log based metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui). Ignore the next screen and go to Monitoring > Alerting. Click on "Create new policy", find your metric and select "Rolling Window" to whatever time period you need. For testing I used 1 minute. Then set "Rollind windows function" to "mean".

[image]

Now configure when the alert has to be triggered - I chose over 3 (within 1 minute window).

[image]

On the next screen you select [notification channel](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options). In case of Slack it has to be configured first in "[Notification Channels](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/notifications)".

You can save policy the policy now.

After a few minutes I gathered enough data to generate two incidents:
[image]

And here's some [alerting related documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts) that may help you understand how to use them.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation and glad I could be of help !